# Tree-width of a quadratic pseudo-Boolean function

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, discrete-optimization, operations-research, quadratic-programming

A [pseudo-Boolean function](http://rutcor.rutgers.edu/~boros/Papers/2002-DAM-BH.pdf) $f : \mathbb{B}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is of the following form.

$$
f \left(x_1, \ldots, x_n\right) = \sum_{S\subseteq V} c_S \prod_{j \in S} x_j
$$
Here $c_S \in \mathbb{R}$, $S$ is the set of all boolean variables, and $S$ is the set of all terms in the polynomial.

The co-occurrence graph is defined as follows.

> If a pseudo-Boolean function $f:\mathbb{B}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is
>   given by its unique multi-linear polynomial, a graph $G_f = \left(V,
>  E\right)$ is called its  co-occurrence graph, in which $\left(i,
>  j\right) \in E$ (for $i, j \in V, i \ne j$) iff $f$ has a term for
>   which $S \supseteq \left\{i, j\right\}$ and $c_S \ne 0$.

The tree-width of $f$ is defined as the tree-width of $G_f$.

We know that in general it is NP-hard to determine the tree-width.

**My question:**

What do we know about the complexity of determining the tree-width when the pseudo-Boolean function is quadratic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is NP-hard (NP-complete in the yes/no answer version), here is a complete proof of it : (you will see that the problems are very very close)

Initial problem : Given a graph $G=(V,E)$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$, is the tree-width of $G$ smaller than $k$?

New problem : Given a quadratic pseudo-boolean function $f$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$, is the tree-width of $f$ smaller than $k$?

Given a graph $G=(V,E)$ where $V=(x_1,...,x_n)$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$, I can write in polynomial time the quadratic pseudo-boolean function $f(x_1,...,x_n) = \sum_{(i,j) \in E}x_ix_j$, and define an instance of the new problem

Is the tree-width of $f$ smaller than smaller than $k$?

Both problems obviously have the same answer, so the old problem is easier than the new which is NP-hard. Since the new one is in NP, it is NP-complete.